# Attempt to de-reference a null object (Custom object)

Tags: apex, process-builder

This code is invoked using process builder and condition to satisfy for firing process builder and creating multiple records is choosing value called "Yes" under a picklist called "Approved" on Parent Object which is "Opportunity Contract".

In sandbox this Code is working fine with all custom profiles, when i give them **modify all permission** for both the custom objects.

In production this code is working for systems administrator alone and not working for other **profiles even with modify all permission** and i getting following error and not able to save the record for creating multiple child records.

Infact for a particular custom profile called Finance, i have cloned system administrator profile and reassigned to them as NewFinance, still i am getting error.

**Attempt to de-reference a null object**

Lookup fields on the both objects include, Account, Contract and Opportunity

Here is the code, any suggestions are highly appreciated

```
public class OppConAMInvocableClass {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Insert Child Records for Opportunity Contracts' description='Inserts the child records based on number of contract years.')
  public static void insertChildRecords(List<Opportunity_Contract__c> parentList) {
      List<Annual_Maintenance__c> childrecords = new List<Annual_Maintenance__c>();        
      for(Opportunity_Contract__c parent : parentList) {
        Integer numberYears = Integer.valueOf(parent.Contract_Years__c);
        for(Integer i=1;i<numberYears;i++) {
        //Account acct = [SELECT Id FROM Account where Id = :e.WhatId];
        Integer j = i + 1;          
        Annual_Maintenance__c child = new Annual_Maintenance__c();


        Child.Anniversary_Date__c=Parent.Annual_Renewal_Date__c.addYears(i);  
        Child.Name=Parent.Name+'-'+Child.Anniversary_Date__c.year();
        Child.Number_of_sites__c=Parent.Number_of_Sites__c;
        Child.Opportunity_Department__c =Parent.Opportunity_Department__c;
        Child.Account__c=Parent.Account_Name__c;
        Child.Primary_Contact__c=Parent.Primary_Contact__c;
        Child.Annual_Maintenance_Start_Date__c=Parent.Contract_Start_Date__c;
        Child.Annual_Maintenance_End_Date__c=Parent.Contract_End_Date__c;
        Child.Opportunity_Name__c=Parent.Opportunity_Name__c;
        Child.Anniversary_Date__c=Parent.Annual_Renewal_Date__c;
        Child.Sales_Territory__c=Parent.Sales_Territory__c;
        Child.Annual_Maintenance_Amount__c=Parent.SMS_Maintenance_Amount__c;
    child.Opportunity_Contract__c=parent.Id;
    childrecords.add(child);
    }
  }    
Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(childrecords);
/*
List<ID> itemIds = new List<ID>();
for (Database.SaveResult result : results) {
  if (result.isSuccess()) {
    itemIds.add(result.getId());
  }
}
```

Comment: If there is record type on object then make sure that picklist values are added in record type  and record type is added in your profile.

Comment: Probably your code breaks when accessing .addYears or .year functions as you need to do a null check on fields before calling function with dot operator.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?  Please edit your original post to include the stack trace if available.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies, the code started working after i recompiled all apex classes in production.